# How to include HTML tags when making a React\Http\Message\Response (ReactPHP)

Tags: html, server, response, reactphp

How can I write tags from HTML in React\Http\Message\Response?

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use React\EventLoop\Loop;
use React\Http\HttpServer;
use React\Http\Message\Response;
use React\Socket\SocketServer;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = Loop::get();
$server = new HttpServer(function (ServerRequestInterface $request) {
  return new Response(
    200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'], "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
  );
});
$socket = new SocketServer('127.0.0.1:8000');
$server->listen($socket);

echo 'Listening on ' . str_replace('tcp', 'http', $socket->getAddress()) . PHP_EOL;
$loop->run();
```

My code writes out "<h1>Hello World</h1>;" instead of making an h1 element with the contents of "Hello World". How can I make it return an h1 element instead of just writing it out with tags

Answer (score 0):

ReactPHP core developer here. Through the `Content-Type` header you're telling the browser the content is `JSON` with the current value of `application/json`. When you set the `Content-Type` header to `text/html` the browser will render it as HTML.